# 70's or 80's book about werewolves folklore

Tags: story-identification, books, werewolf

I had a number of books as a child, but one in particular keeps coming to mind and if anyone could help me identify it, that would be great. Here's what I remember...

It was a book on werewolves, I believe from either the 70's or 80's, it told how people believed one could become a werewolf and other folklore regarding them.

If I remember correctly I don't believe the book was that thick and I think the cover was orange.

Comment: I am also looking for What could be the same book, It was called how to become a werewolf and I think I bought it from scholastic books from the school I was in. I know I had it but can't find any info on it at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After typing a long description here to help someone help you find this book I found it: ["Meet the Werewolf"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2778674-meet-the-werewolf).

[image: cover] [image: Orange cover]

The description you typed is what I remembered. 
According to [this review](https://web.archive.org/web/20160809182906/http://www.sethmad.com/2014/10/turn-your-children-into-werewolves-a-halloween-book-hunt):

> The book was about werewolves. Nonfiction. A sort of guide, as if werewolves were an actual rare species worthy of study, like secretary birds or Kardashians. This was a book for children. In particular I remembered a section with **detailed instructions about turning oneself into a werewolf. Oneself being a *child***. And I’d found this book in my *elementary school’s library*.

I hope it's what you're looking for also.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please can you add more detail to this answer, e.g. by including a description of the book and perhaps linking to Wikipedia or GoodReads? More detailed guidance on writing story-ID answers may be found [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394).

Comment: That's the one. I had forgotten I had asked about the book and just happened across this today. After looking this book up, this is the one I remember. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is great! I remembered reading this in the 2nd grade and trying to become a werewolf, Lol!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the publication date (my edition doesn't seem to say) but could it be [*Werewolves*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1887867.Werewolves). It has that sort of information in it, it's a thin book does seem to be aimed at children / teens and is orange!

[image: Werewolves by Nigel Suckling cover]

Upon flicking through it turns out it references films from the 90s. Maybe a reprint (which could explain why my edition has no date) but maybe not after all. It is a good book though!

Answer (score 1):

Not a children's book, but can I suggest [*The Book of Werewolves*](https://www.bookdepository.com/Book-Werewolves-Sabine-Baring-Gould/9781605203355).  It looks like a 19-th century anthropological study on the subject.

Fun bonus: Loren Coleman wrote the intro.